# How to run main file using gradle?

Tags: java, testing, gradle, intellij-idea, program-entry-point

I have an application in java written in IntelliJ using gradle. Right now I can run tests but I'd like to run main file to check execution by myself. Does anyone know how to run main file?

Comment: Do you want to run it in IntelliJ IDEA or in the command line using Gradle?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you use Java. In this case:

1. Apply [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html)
2. Define mainClassName property

The `build.gradle.kts` fill be like:

```
plugins {
    application
}

application {
    mainClassName = "org.gradle.sample.Main"
}
```

Next you can start application via `gradlew run`